# Case SQL and count each row

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by

How can I get the required results below? I could get all unique categories by adding `DISTINCT`, but in retrieving the *total* of each category the query below doesn't work.

#### Table structure: BEER

```
ID | NAME | TYPE | ALCOHOL |
```

#### Required Result

```
category   |  total
----------------------------
Light      | 34
Medium     | 2
Normal     | 3
Heavy      | 4
Knock out  | 5
```

#### My SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 3 THEN 'Light'
        WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 5 THEN 'Medium'
        WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 7 THEN 'Normal'
        WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 9 THEN 'Heavy'
        WHEN b.ALCOHOL >= 9 THEN 'Knock out'
   END AS category
FROM BEER b;
```

Could anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: You need a GROUP BY too.

Comment: what is total column? is it count(*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `count()` and a `group by`. I have used a CTE to avoid a brutal `group by`

```
with CTE as
(
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 3 THEN 'Light'
            WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 5 THEN 'Medium'
                WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 7 THEN 'Normal'
                WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 9 THEN 'Heavy'
                WHEN b.ALCOHOL >= 9 THEN 'Knock out'
   END AS category,
   b.Alcohol
     FROM BEER b
)
select category, count(alcohol)
from CTE
group by category
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a count and group by:

```
SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM (
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 3 THEN 'Light'
         WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 5 THEN 'Medium'
         WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 7 THEN 'Normal'
         WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 9 THEN 'Heavy'
         ELSE 'Knock out'
    END AS Category
  FROM BEER) b
GROUP BY Category
```

The subquery is used to simplify the `GROUP BY`, because Oracle doesn't support `GROUP BY 1` syntax.

Also note the simpler `ELSE` in the `CASE`

Comment: Oracle doesn't support `GROUP BY 1`, alas, it would be neat if it did

Comment: What happens if Beer.Alcohol is null?

Comment: Derived table, my no 1 choice here!

Comment: @apc I've just spent the last couple of minutes googling that very point, and sadly it's true. Yet another reason to ditch oracle.

Comment: @john my spidey sense tells me the column is `NOT NULL` :)

Comment: @jarlh yes, not only is it more portable, it doesn't look like a train wreck (any more than SQL tends toward wreckage anyway)

Answer (score 1):

you can apply `GROUP BY` on the `CASE` and find `COUNT`

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 3 THEN 'Light'
        WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 5 THEN 'Medium'
        WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 7 THEN 'Normal'
        WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 9 THEN 'Heavy'
        WHEN b.ALCOHOL >= 9 THEN 'Knock out'
   END AS category,
   count(*) total
FROM BEER b
GROUP BY 
    CASE WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 3 THEN 'Light'
        WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 5 THEN 'Medium'
        WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 7 THEN 'Normal'
        WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 9 THEN 'Heavy'
        WHEN b.ALCOHOL >= 9 THEN 'Knock out'
   END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a aggregate function with the same condition along with `group by` like

```
sum(CASE WHEN b.ALCOHOL < 3 THEN 1 else 0 end)
....
from tbl1
group by some_col
```